# Cannot package a debug application (cannot create .apk)

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am following this tutorial to create .apk file:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android

On step#4 when I run the following command nothing happens:

> sencha package run packager.json

Absolutely nothing happens. There is no success/error message shown and command prompt is ready to take the next command.

Here is my config file for debugging:

```
{
    "applicationName":"myApp",
    "applicationId":"com.techleadz.myApp",
    "iconName":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad_myApp.png",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "outputPath":"build/",
    "inputPath":"build/native/",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"AndroidEmulator",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"C:/Users/Administrator/.android/debug.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"androiddebugkey",
    "sdkPath":"C:/android-sdk-windows/",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu ?
   if so there is  some problem in sencha tools for packaging for native.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified a certificate password or an android list target you must have installed the disk image for the list target that you are trying to include and target must be atleast 7

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you please provide any link where I can read more about this? I didn't read anything like this in Sencha Touch docs.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android i know its a pain but read it carefully and do as it says